# Return key (from dictionary) if values are present in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
meals = {'Pasta Bolognese' : ['pasta', 'tomato sauce', 'ground beef'],
    'Cold Salad' : ['greens', 'tomato'],
    'Warm Salad' : ['greens', 'tomato', 'corn', 'chickpeas', 'quinoa'],
    'Sandwich' : ['bread', 'turkey slices', 'cheese', 'sauce']}
```

and a list:

```
ingredients = ['bread', 'chickpeas', 'tomato', 'greens']
```

I want to get a key from dictionary if all its values are present in the list. So for current situation I want to get 'Cold Salad' since both 'greens' and 'tomato' are in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
>>> next((k for k, v in meals.items() if set(v).issubset(ingredients)))
'Cold Salad'
>>>
```

Notice that this code uses a generator with `next`, also to have a more efficient way to have multiple `in` statements, instead of `all` and a loop with `in`, I used [`set.issubset`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issubset.html) to check if all values in one set is a *subset* of the other.

If there might be no matches, add a `None` at the end:

```
next((k for k, v in meals.items() if set(v).issubset(ingredients)), None)
```

Or anything, you could replace `None` with anything i.e. `"No Match"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension as follows:

```
meals = {'Pasta Bolognese' : ['pasta', 'tomato sauce', 'ground beef'],
        'Cold Salad' : ['greens', 'tomato'],
        'Warm Salad' : ['greens', 'tomato', 'corn', 'chickpeas', 'quinoa'],
        'Sandwich' : ['bread', 'turkey slices', 'cheese', 'sauce'], 
        'Another Item': ['greens', 'bread']}

ingredients = ['bread', 'chickpeas', 'tomato', 'greens']

output = [key for key, value in meals.items() if set(value).issubset(ingredients)]

print(output)
```

Result:

```
['Cold Salad', 'Another Item']
```

You will notice I have added `Another Item` to test that more than one matching item will be returned.